# how to move multiple images from a folder to another folder in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to move multiple images from one folder to another, using `shutil.move()` , I have saved image names in a CSV file. 
ex: `[img1 , img25, img55....]`

I Have tried the below code

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil

cop_folder = path to folder containing images    
destination_folder = path wher i want to move the images


df = pd.read_csv('', header = None)    
for i in df:       
    if i in cop_folder:
        shutil.move( i, dest_folder)
    else:
        print('fail')
```

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


def move_file(old_file_path, new_directory):
    if not os.path.isdir(new_directory):
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    base_name = os.path.basename(old_file_path)
    new_file_path = os.path.join(new_directory, base_name)
    # Deletes a file if that file already exists there, you can change this behavior
    if os.path.exists(new_file_path):
        os.remove(new_file_path)
    os.rename(old_file_path, new_file_path)


cop_folder = 'origin-folder\\'

destination_folder = 'dest_folder\\'

df = pd.read_csv('files.csv', header=None)

for i in df[0]:
    filename = os.path.join(cop_folder, i)
    move_file(filename, destination_folder)
```

The file names inside the csv must have an extension. If they don't, then you should use filename = os.path.join(cop_folder, i + '.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, firstly you are iterating over a dataframe which will return the column labels not the values - that's what's causing the error the you posted. If you really want to use pandas just to import a CSV then you could change it to `for i in df.iterrows()` but even then it won't simply return the file name, it will return a series object. You'd probably be better off using the standard CSV module to read the CSV. That way your filenames will be read in as a list and will behave as you intended.

Secondly unless there is something else going on in your code you can't look for files in a folder using the 'in' keyword, you'll need to construct a full filepath by concatenating the filename and the folder path.